# I can't get text form radio buttoon

Tags: java, android

sombody can help me,,,i want to get text form radio button to insert into database, and i not get error massage but the text form radio button not insert to database

this my code

```js
tiang = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNotiang);
        rd1=(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.JTM) ;
        rd2=(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.JTR) ;
        rd3=(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.TR) ;
        ton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        ton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        

        ton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM pdil WHERE tiang = '" +
                        tiang.getText().toString() + "'", null);
                if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Sudah Ada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (rd1.isChecked()) {
                    db.execSQL("insert into pdil(tiang,long,lat,jenis) values('" +
                            tiang.getText().toString() + "','" +
                            gps.getLongitude() + "','" +
                            gps.getLatitude() + "','"+ rd1.getText().toString() +"')");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Berhasil", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    MainActivity.ma.RefreshList();
                    finish();
                }else if (rd2.isChecked()) {
                    db.execSQL("insert into pdil(tiang,long,lat,jenis) values('" +
                            tiang.getText().toString() + "','" +
                            gps.getLongitude() + "','" +
                            gps.getLatitude() + "','" + rd2.getText().toString() + "')");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Berhasil", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    MainActivity.ma.RefreshList();
                    finish();
                }else if (rd3.isChecked()) {
                    db.execSQL("insert into pdil(tiang,long,lat,jenis) values('" +
                            tiang.getText().toString() + "','" +
                            gps.getLongitude() + "','" +
                            gps.getLatitude() + "','" + rd3.getText().toString() + "')");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Berhasil", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    MainActivity.ma.RefreshList();
                    finish();
                }
            };
        });
```

please help me...:(

this DataHelper

```js
public class DataHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "newpdil3.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public DataHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String sql = "create table pdil(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY   AUTOINCREMENT,tiang text null,lat text null,long text null,area null,rayon null,jenis text null);";
        Log.d("Data", "onCreate: " + sql);
        db.execSQL(sql);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

Comment: this isnt javascript...

Comment: can you please post your DbHelper class?

Comment: i was post DataHelper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update your `DataHelper` class as below:**

```
public class DataHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "newpdil3.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public DataHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String sql = "create table pdil(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, tiang text null, lat text null, long text null, area text null, rayon text null, jenis text null);";
        Log.d("Data", "onCreate: " + sql);
        db.execSQL(sql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void insertData(String tiang, String lat, String long, String jenis) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put("tiang", tiang);
        values.put("lat", lat);
        values.put("long", long);
        values.put("jenis", jenis);

        // Insert data 
        db.insert("pdil", null, values);
    }

    .................
    ........................
}
```

**Update `onClick()` method as below:**

```
DataHelper dbHelper  = new DataHelper(this);

ton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM pdil WHERE tiang = '" +
                    tiang.getText().toString() + "'", null);

            if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Sudah Ada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (rd1.isChecked()) {
                dbHelper.insertData(tiang.getText().toString(), String.valueOf(gps.getLatitude()), String.valueOf(gps.getLongitude()), rd1.getText().toString()); 

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Berhasil", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                MainActivity.ma.RefreshList();
                finish();
            }else if (rd2.isChecked()) {
                dbHelper.insertData(tiang.getText().toString(), String.valueOf(gps.getLatitude()), String.valueOf(gps.getLongitude()), rd2.getText().toString()); 

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Berhasil", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                MainActivity.ma.RefreshList();
                finish();
            }else if (rd3.isChecked()) {
                dbHelper.insertData(tiang.getText().toString(), String.valueOf(gps.getLatitude()), String.valueOf(gps.getLongitude()), rd3.getText().toString());      

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Berhasil", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                MainActivity.ma.RefreshList();
                finish();
            }
        };
```

Comment: are you getting any error. Please add some log in your conditions

Comment: no error log, and i try to use Log.e("radio",rd1.getText().toString()) , i got the value E/radio: JTM...

Comment: did you used updated create table statement: "create table pdil(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, tiang text null, lat text null, long text null, area null, rayon null, jenis text null);";            use this and uninstall and reinstall your app and try agian

Comment: make sure your table created properly and add log into insertdata table. `long result = db.insert(....)`. try to print the `result` value

Comment: when i print the log.e , i got the value E/hasil: Ghhu
E/lat: -6.657356666666668
E/lon: 106.87434333333334
E/jenis: TR ,,, the radio is jenis.. but it no insert to database

Comment: what is the value of db.insert()?

Comment: I/System.out: rayon=53261 tiang=Hjih area=53TSK lat=-6.657406666666667 long=106.87400833333335 jenis=JTM
, when i see the result i get the radio value..is jenis=JTM

Comment: I have updated create table statement as: String sql = "create table pdil(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, tiang text null, lat text null, long text null, area text null, rayon text null, jenis text null);";  try this and uninstall and reinstall app

Comment: still no work, in this case just jenis not inserted to database, other value have insert to database..

Comment: Glad to know that :)

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize the above code as first of all group the radio buttons

```
    ton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM pdil WHERE tiang = '" +
                    tiang.getText().toString() + "'", null);
            if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Sudah Ada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {

             RadioGroup rg1= (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_grp);
            if(rg1.getCheckedRadioButtonId()!=-1){
                int id= rg1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                View radioButton = rg1.findViewById(id);
                int radioId = radioGroup.indexOfChild(radioButton);
                RadioButton btn = (RadioButton) rg1.getChildAt(radioId);
                String selection = (String) btn.getText();

                db.execSQL("insert into pdil(tiang,long,lat,jenis) values('" +
                        tiang.getText().toString() + "','" +
                        gps.getLongitude() + "','" +
                        gps.getLatitude() + "','"+ selection +"')");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Berhasil", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                MainActivity.ma.RefreshList();
                finish();
            }

            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: i use your code and i got error , java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.RadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()' on a null object reference
                      at com.mobile.lunatique.dataassetapps.BuatBiodata$1.onClick(BuatBiodata.java:63)

Comment: did u close in radio group and did u assign rg1